# Create a hash of checkbox buttons that are active among a Twitter Bootstrap Button group on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple groups of [Twitter Bootstrap checkbox groups](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html). I would like to create a hash of all active (i.e., Bootsrtap adds the "active" class) buttons when any one of the checkbox buttons are clicked. Suppose the html is like so after a few clicks:

```
<div id="horizontal" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button class="btn active" data-hposition="1">Left</button>
  <button class="btn" data-hposition="2">Middle</button>
  <button class="btn active"data-hposition="3">Right</button>
</div>
<div id="vertical" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
  <button class="btn" data-vposition="1">Top</button>
  <button class="btn active" data-vposition="2">Center</button>
  <button class="btn active" data-vposition="3">Bottom</button>
</div>
```

I started out simple with just one div but I don't get the right result:

```
<script>
  $('#horizonatal').click( function(){
      var paramsHash = {};
      var hids = [];
    $('.active').each( function() {
      paramsHash.hids.push($(this).data('hposition'));
  })
      console.log(paramsHash.hids);    
})
</script>
```

Using the above html, when I click on "Right" I get something like `[1,undefined]` in the console.

Eventually, I would like to get a hash to Post like `{ {'hids', [ 1, 3 ]}, {'vids', [  2, 3, ]} }`

I attempted a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGxxC/7/) but I don't think I am loading the Bootstrap stuff properly because I don't see the buttons going to active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there are typos in your data attributes(*on the fiddle*) and also you select all the `.active` classes not those that belong to the *horizontal* div and as they don't have a *data-hposition* attribute it returns *undefinded*, Try the following:

```
$('#horizontal').click( function(){
      var paramsHash = {
              hids: [],
            //vidz: []
          }
    $('.active', this).each( function() {
      paramsHash.hids.push($(this).data('hposition'));
   // paramsHash.vidz.push($(this).data('classroom'));
    })
      console.log(paramsHash);    
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YGxxC/1/)

---

Please note that they are *Button* tags not Radio Buttons.

Comment: Thank you for responding and sorting through my mess of a question. I corrected the spelling errors and my incorrect reference to the radio button.

I am trying to build a hash of checkbox ids.

Comment: Okay. Now that I have fixed my mistaken references to radio buttons where I meant checkbox buttons (among other errors), can you tell me how I could collect all of the checkboxes that are clicked in a group? Also, is it possible to make it work on the jtfiddle (i.e., Bootstrap checkbox button.js removes and adds active class)?

Comment: @JHo You are welcome, when do you want to collect the data? what kind of data? currently your markup has no `checkbox`.

Comment: I would like to collect the data when any of buttons are clicked in either div. The Twitter Bootstrap linked to has `button` group that behaves like a set of checkboxes. I would like to collect the integer value(s) from the data attribute and post as a hash. I tuned up the [fiddle]( http://jsfiddle.net/YGxxC/11/) (in just 11 versions) to now show the Twitter Bootstrap checkbox-button

Comment: I have gotten a bit further with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGxxC/25/). I have it doing everything I need but there is one catch: it does not count the button I have just clicked and it counts the button I have just unclicked. Is there an easy way to sequence it so that it pushes the clicked button into the right part of the hash without a lot of extra if-else mumbo jumbo?

Comment: @JHo Hey, your click handler works well but sooner than adding a class, is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/YGxxC/27/

Comment: That works perfectly and it's very succinct. Thank you for sticking with it!